# How to bold tag value in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

Code :

```
<root>
{
  for $x in ./root/StatementDetail
  let $PolicyNo := fn:upper-case($x/PolicyNo)
  group by $PolicyNo
  order by $PolicyNo
  return <statement>
        <StatementDetail>{$PolicyNo}</StatementDetail>
        <NetAmountSum>{sum($x/NetAmount)}</NetAmountSum>
      </statement>
}
</root>
```

I want to bold {$PolicyNo} inside StatementDetail tag . how will i do this Please help me out.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is 'bold'?

Answer (score 1):

There is no notion of boldness in XQuery or XML.

There may be a notion of boldness in a particular XML schema which you might target via your XQuery, but we couldn't tell you without knowing more about the vocabulary of your target.

If it's similar to HTML, changing

```
    <StatementDetail>{$PolicyNo}</StatementDetail>
```

to

```
    <StatementDetail><b>{$PolicyNo}</b></StatementDetail>
```

might work, provided that the `StatementDetail` element accepts a `b` child element.

It is also possible that this vocabulary itself does not have any notion of boldness.  You might have to modify a presentation layer downstream of this XML in order to add boldness.